# Expected duration of a die game

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, dice

In a 2 person game, the player who first obtains a $6$ wins. I'm trying to determine the expected number of die rolls needed before a winner is determined. (One turn
consists of two die rolls, assuming that neither player won in that turn).

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

This problem can be modeled by a geometric distribution with probability $p$, and by virtue of this the expectation, $E[X] = \frac{1}{p}$. Now since, the probability of getting a $6$ is $\frac{1}{6}$, then $E[X] = 6$. I'm wondering if this is correct, or am I missing something.

Comment: If the first player throws a $6$, do you stop?  If not, suppose they both throw $6$.  Is it a tie, or do they keep playing?

Comment: The game seems to be played in turns. The first player throws the die. If he wins, the game stops there. Otherwise the second player gets his first chance and so on. That's what I've assumed while posting my answer.

Comment: The $6$ is the correct expectation for the number of **rolls**, on the assumption the game ends immediately after the first $6$. The number of rolls has geometric distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to find the expected number of turns for the game to end. That is given by:
$$ \sum_{r=0}^\infty rP_r\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{(by definition)} $$
where $ P_r $ is the probability for the game to end in the $r^\text{th}$ turn.

Now, let's see the probability for the game to end in the zeroth turn (that is, the players have just begun playing).

The game will end in the zeroth turn iff either the first player wins or the second player wins. Thus, the probability is $ P_0 = \dfrac 16 + \left(\dfrac 56\right)\dfrac 16 $

Similarly, $ P_1 = \left(\dfrac 56\right)^2\dfrac 16 + \left(\dfrac 56\right)^3\dfrac 16 $

It's easy to see that $ P_r = \left(\dfrac 56\right)^{2r}\dfrac 16 + \left(\dfrac 56\right)^{2r+1}\dfrac 16 = \dfrac{275}{1296}\left(\dfrac{25}{36}\right)^{r-1} $

Thus, the expected number of turns of the game is:

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{r=0}^\infty r\dfrac{275}{1296}\left(\dfrac{25}{36}\right)^{r-1} \\\\
&=\dfrac{275}{1296} \sum_{r=0}^\infty r\left(\dfrac{25}{36}\right)^{r-1}\\\\
&=\dfrac{275}{1296}\dfrac{1}{\left(1-\dfrac{25}{36}\right)^2} = \boxed{\boxed{\dfrac{25}{11}}}
\end{align}$$

where in the last step, I've used the fact that:
$$ \sum_{r=0}^\infty rx^{r-1} = \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2} \forall |x| < 1 $$

So, the expected number of turns turns out to be (sic) is $\dfrac{25}{11}$.

**EDIT**:

As suggested by Ross Millikan, it's better to start the counting from $1$. In that case, there's a slight change. Our $P_r$ becomes $ \dfrac{11}{36} \left(\dfrac{25}{36}\right)^{r-1}$.

Hence, the 'new' expected number of turns is $\dfrac{36}{11}$.

Comment: The game seems to end whenever either player throws $6$, not when both players throw $6$

Comment: Yes, that's why the probability of the game ending in the $r^\text{th}$ turn is $\left(\dfrac 56\right)^{2r}\dfrac 16 + \left(\dfrac 56\right)^{2r+1}\dfrac 16$ and not: $P_r = \left(\dfrac 56\right)^{2r}\dfrac 16 \cdot \left(\dfrac 56\right)^{2r+1}\dfrac 16$

Comment: The game ends if either the first player puts a six, or the second does so. But for the second to do so, the first must put a non-six.

Comment: It is a little odd to start counting turns from $0$ instead of $1$. As each turn is the last with probability about $\frac 13$, the expected number of turns should be around $3$.  $25$ is way too high.

Comment: I'm wondering if this game was generalized to $k$ dice being thrown simultaneously and the ﬁrst player to obtain a total of k (or more) 6’s, accumulated over all his throws, wins the
game. Would this game run for fewer turns?

Comment: @RossMillikan, my bad! I forgot an eleven in the denominator. If we start the counting from $0$, then the expected number of turns turns out to be (pun very much intended), $\frac{25}{11}$. Otherwise, on starting from $1$, it turns out to be $\frac{36}{11}$, which lies near $3$. I first ran a program to check, and you *turned* (sic!) out to be correct. However, could you explain how you got the $\frac 13$ and from that, $3$? I don't understand what you said.

Comment: In a geometric distribution, if the hitting probability is $p$, the expected number of tries is $\frac 1p$.  This is where OP gets an expected number of rolls of one die to be $6$.

Comment: I don't know pretty much anything about geometric distributions. Just had a look at it on wiki and didn't understand much. However, as you're saying, the answer must be *exactly* $3$, right? Why's it different?

Comment: @ParthThakkar: The expected number of rolls $r$ is 6, and the number of turns $t$ would be exactly 3 *if* the number of turns in a particular game were $\frac{r}{2}$. However, the number of turns is $\lceil\frac{r}{2}\rceil$ ($\frac{r}{2}$ rounded up to the nearest integer). This explains why the expected number of *turns* is greater than 3.

Comment: @SteveKass: Thanks! I had figured out the $\frac r 2$ part, but the exactness-part was unclear. Thanks again :)